# Finding a "free theorem"

Tags: haskell, free-theorem

How do I derive the free theorem for the type:

```
data F a = C1 Nat | C2 Bool Nat a
```

where `Nat` is simply `data Nat = Z | S Nat`?

In principle, this can be answered by the Haskell 'free-theorems' package, but it's too elderly to compile under any GHC version I can reasonably install.

Comment: Free theorems are usually associated to polymorphic function types. Otherwise, IIRC, you get a trivial theorem, e.g. `fmap f = fmap f` where `fmap :: (a->b)-> F a -> F b` is the functor instance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is [an online generator for free theorems at](http://www-ps.informatik.uni-kiel.de/~sad/FreeTheorems/cgi-bin/free-theorems-webui.cgi), and when it was down a little while ago I [created an alternative UI](http://free-theorems.nomeata.de/) that runs completely in the browser (using `reflex-dom`).

But the deeper problem is that free theorems, in the sense of these packages, are properties of *polymorphic functions*, so in order to answer your question, you have to give a function (like `map`) whose free theorem you are interested in.